# Visual Studio crashes on Microsoft.Build.ni.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am running Windows 7 Pro x64, Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. I recently installed Telerik's OpenAccess platform for a project. It was working fine yesterday, but today I can't open any project. Websites open, but can't build.

I have gone back to a previous System Restore, still didn't work. I uninstalled Telerik, still didn't work. I uninstalled Visual Studio, still didn't work. I'm guessing that Visual Studio doesn't do a very good clean uninstall. Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Would a full/complete uninstall/reinstall (following these [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246604%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) make it work? Or should I go back to a system image that I have from last week?

Details:

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version: 11.0.50727.1
  Application Timestamp: 5011ecaa
  Fault Module Name: Microsoft.Build.ni.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.0.30319.17929
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4ffa85ef
  Exception Code: 4000001e
  Exception Offset: 0015bb0b
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 4573
  Additional Information 2: 45733103af735ff41371b17e98563272
  Additional Information 3: 4bd5
  Additional Information 4: 4bd53bb8e059301da3f7505a70c67f13

This is the activity Log where it fails:

257
    2013/08/23 13:11:30.339
    Information
    VisualStudio
    Begin package load [Visual Studio Build Manager Package]
    {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}
  
  
    258
    2013/08/23 13:11:30.344
    Error
    VisualStudio
    SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Build Manager Package]
    {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}

---

80131604
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  
  
    259
    2013/08/23 13:11:30.345
    Error
    VisualStudio
    End package load [Visual Studio Build Manager Package]
    {B718A162-0361-4B0E-920B-D88D70BE609B}

---

80131604
    Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Try cleaning your registry and temporary files using a cleaner software such as CCleaner

Comment: You'd better get a new hard disk soon.

Comment: I'm trying the CCleaner. It is a new hard drive. Why do you say that?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva - I cleaned out the registry and removed everything from Temp Files, still no luck. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This won't help anyone else, but I figured I would put it out there, maybe someone else will come up with a better solution. Sadly, I wasn't able to make anything work. I ended up having to go back to a previous system image. Thank goodness for backups!

We'll see what happens next time I have to add a VS plug-in.